# The flexbox is not taking the right width Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have created a flex table and it is not showing me the right tables only the first table it is good and others are not in the same width.
I tried to put in another div the class planned but then is not showing me in the row.

Below you can find a code.
[image: Here is the photo what looks like for the moment]

```
<div class="planning-videx">
    <div class="name-block" *ngFor="let valueItem of showVI()">
      {{valueItem.name}}
      <div class="planned">
        {{actualCosts | moneyFormat}}
      </div>
      <div class="planned">
        {{plannedCosts | moneyFormat}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS

```
$row-background-color: white;
$row-height: 100%;
$content-height: 45px;
.planning-videx {
  @extend .vp-column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: $row-height;
  .name-block {
    @extend %common-block;
    @include center(false, true);
    @include justify-content(space-between);
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    div.planned {
      @extend %flexbox;
      @include center(false, true);
      border-left: solid thin $border-color;
      padding: 0 5px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 100%;
    }

  }
  .costs-block {
    @extend %common-block;
    @include center();
    @include justify-content(flex-end);
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

%common-block {
  @extend .vp-row;
  background-color: $row-background-color;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  min-height: $content-height;
  border: solid thin $border-color;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: You may also want to provide the code for your mixins.

Comment: @Pytth Sorry I didn't understand because here is all my code what I have writed ?

Answer (score 0):

I would set a flex basis or a set width to the money category and then set a 'flex: 1' to the title so that it can grow into the remaining space.